# Flutter: Is it possible to access the parent State of a BuildContext?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to access a `BuildContext`'s parent state from the `BuildContext` object?

For example:

```
class importantMethods {
  static int importantVariable = 1;
  static void increment(BuildContext context) {
    context.<parentState>.setState((){
        importantVariable += 1;
    });//I wonder if this function is possible
  }
}

class importantWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return importantWidgetState();
  }
}

class importantWidgetState extends State<importantWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text(importantMethods.importantVariable.toString()),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("Increment"),
            onPressed: () {
              importantMethods.increment(context);
            },
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `Provider` to control the state of both parent and child so that you can asses the state from anywhere below the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply hand the parents context (and name it something useful like `parentContext`) then this should be possible. However, I would strongly suggest against this pattern. Your state will start to look like spaghetti very quickly.

I'd suggest creating an extra module that you'd use to do simple state management between modules. You could create a file called "statemanager.dart" and import it wherever you needed to access the current state. It would look something like this. It would work in a pinch for a smaller project but if you need to scale up even more, I'd suggest looking into packages such as [flutter redux](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux).

```
Map<String,dynamic> store = {};

void setStore(String key,dynamic data)
{
  store[key] = data;
}

dynamic getStore(String key)
{
  return store[key];
}
```